# 'A call to PInvoke function..' error with c++ DLL method to c#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have to use this dll function coming from a C++ project in my C# code.

C++:

```
BOOL __stdcall ReadString(LPTSTR valueName, LPTSTR value, LPTSTR defaultValue, int subTree, LPCTSTR serverName, long stnNumber) {
    int ris;
    CScatRegistry reg(subTree, FALSE, serverName, stnNumber);

    ris = reg.Read(valueName, value, defaultValue);

    return ris;
}
```

I'm importing with DllImport like this:

C#:

```
[DllImport("DHRegistry.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern long ReadString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string valueName,
                              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string value,
                              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string defaultValue,
                              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int subTree,
                              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string serverName,
                              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)] long stnNumber);
```

and when I call 'ReadString' function it shows the standard 'A call to PInvoke function '[…]' has unbalanced the stack' error.

```
public string fooNameFunction(string strNAME, string strDefaultValue, int pathKey = Constants.REG_SUBT_TEMP, string serverName = null, long stnNumber = 0)
    long lRegReturnValue;
    lRegReturnValue = ReadString(strNAME, strValue, strDefaultValue, pathKey, serverName, stnNumber); //error here
    return ""; //has nothing to do with my error
}
```

I've already tried with CallingConvention.Cdecl but the error persists.

Any idea what could happens?

Comment: `long` is 32 bits in C++ on Windows, but `long` is 64 bits in C#. So `stnNumber` should be `int`. The return value should be `int` too, with a non zero value meaning true. It also looks a little like the code expects some of the text arguments to be returned to the caller. That would need `StringBuilder`, and some idea of how large a buffer to allocate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, I didn't know about the `long` size in C++ (my bad).